# Why the std::swap of Bits in a std::bitset instance doesn't work?

Tags: c++

In the following example i expected the swap of the bits. Instead the second bit becomes overwritten, but why and how could i achieve the expected behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<2> test(string("10"));
    cout << test; // Prints "10"
    swap(test[0], test[1]);
    cout << test; // Prints "11", why not "01"?
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is pure nasty. First we have to look at the declaration of swap:

```
template<class T>
void swap(T &left, T &right);
```

Now, `operator[]()` on `bitset` has two overloads:

```
bool operator[](size_type _Pos) const;
reference operator[](size_type _Pos);
```

Here `reference` is `bitset::reference`, a nested class in `bitset` that effectively acts as a proxy reference to the one of the underlying bits. What it encapsulates is the `bitset` and a position in the `bitset`. Because of the declaration of `swap`, the second overload is chosen and we are swapping two `bitset::reference`s. Now here's where it gets nasty. Let's look at a typical implementation of swap:

```
template class<T> swap(T &left, T &right) {
    T temp = left;
    left = right;
    right = temp;
}
```

The problem is that `left` and `right` are both references to a `bitset::reference`. They have the same underlying data (because they are proxies; same meaning the both point to the same `bitset`!) they just encapsulate different positions in that `bitset`. Thus, think of it like this `left` is position 0 in some `bitset` and `right` is position 1 in some `bitset` and that `bitset` is the same `bitset` as `left`! Let's forever refer to this `bitset` as `BS` (chosen intentionally).

So,

```
T temp = left;
```

says that `temp` is position 0 in `BS`.

```
left = right;
```

sets position 0 in left to position 1 in `BS` (which simultaneously changes position 0 in `temp`!)

```
right = temp;
```

sets position 1 in right to position 0 in `BS` (which was just set to position 1 in `BS`!). So at the end of this mess have that position 0 is whatever position 1 was and position 1 is unchanged! Now, because position 0 is the LSB and position 1 is the MSB we have that "10" becomes "11". Ugly.

You can get around this with a [template specialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_specialization):

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    void swap<bitset<2>::reference>(
        bitset<2>::reference &left,
        bitset<2>::reference &right
    ) {
        bool temp = (bool)left;
        left = (bool)right;
        right = (bool)temp;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
int main() {
    bitset<2> test(string("10"));
    cout << test; // Prints "10"
    swap(test[0], test[1]);
    cout << test; // Prints "01", hallelujah!
}
```

Comment: Nice work! Incredibly not even C++0x mentions `swap` at all in relation to bitsets.

Comment: Does this actually compile? `test[0]` is a temporary that you can't take a reference to...

Comment: @Barry Agreed. It seems that when you pass `test[0]` and `test[1]` to `swap`, it returns the value of the requested bit. The only workaround I have found is to explicitly store `test[0]` and `test[1]` ahead of time into two separate variables to yield `std::bitset::reference` and pass this to `swap`. If anyone knows of any better method, please tell. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, since `test[i]` returns a bitset reference rvalue, I don't really understand how `swap` can compile here. My compiler (g++ 4.3.3) tells me:

```
test.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to 
  'swap(std::bitset<2u>::reference, std::bitset<2u>::reference)'
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_move.h:80: note: candidates are: 
  void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::bitset<2u>::reference]
```

Comment: @HansPassant VS accepts this code because of a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775818/vc11-non-const-lvalue-reference-incorrectly-binds-to-rvalue) which allows non-const lvalue references to bind to rvalues. I upvoted the bug (helping convincing Microsoft to fix it) and added a link to this post as an example of a nasty consequence of this bug. I suggest you (everybody) to upvote the bug as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's no value type in C++ to represent a single bit, so when you use the `[]` operator to access an element of a bitset, what you get is a *proxy object* that serves as an alias for the bit you requested. Assigning to that proxy object changes the corresponding bit value in the original bitset object.

As [Victor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003255/why-the-stdswap-of-bits-in-a-stdbitset-instance-doesnt-work/2003286#2003286) shows, your code doesn't compile with GCC. But let's suppose the call to `swap` would compile. You'd get code that amounts to something like this:

```
void swap(std::bitset<2>::reference& a, std::bitset<2>::reference& b)
{
  std::bitset<2>::reference tmp = a;
  a = b;
  b = tmp;
}
```

The `tmp` declaration initializes the variable with `a`, but that doesn't make a copy of the bit. Instead, it makes a copy of the proxy object, so `tmp` *refers* to the same bit in the same bitset that `a` refers to. The next line assigns `b` to `a`, which copies the bit value from the location `a` refers to and stores it in the bit location `b` refers to. Finally, there's the assignment of `tmp` into `b`. But remember that `tmp` still refers to the bit that `a` refers to. Reading `tmp` is the same as reading `a`, so you ultimately get the same effect you'd get if `swap` were just these two lines:

```
a = b;
b = a;
```

In your code, `a` is 0 and `b` is 1, so with those two assignment statements, 11 is exactly what we'd expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    bitset<128> bs(42);
    bs[11]=0;
    bs[12]=1;
    assert(bs[12]==1);
    printf("bs[11]=%d\n", (int)bs[11]);
    printf("bs[12]=%d\n", (int)bs[12]);
    int bsi = bs[11], bsj=bs[12];
    swap(bsi, bsj);
    bs[11]=bsi;
    bs[12]=bsj;
    printf("bs[11]=%d\n", (int)bs[11]);
    printf("bs[12]=%d\n", (int)bs[12]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]